# Append a data field to a record saved to a table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a table that is generated through a form and this data then filters through to another form. The second form is then ticked off and I need to pull the persons windows ID to the table to complete the recordset. I have been appending to the table but the records all appear after the current saved data. Is there a way to append to the saved records, the identifying fields are DateCompleted and ClientID. 
The SQL that appends the table I want, albeit after the record is -

```
INSERT INTO ChecklistResults ( ManagerID )
SELECT ChecklistResults.ManagerID
FROM ChecklistResults
WHERE (((ChecklistResults.ClientID)=[Forms]![TeamLeader]![ComClientNotFin]) AND ((ChecklistResults.DateCompleted)=[Forms]![TeamLeader]![ComDateSelect]));
```

Is there a way of actually appending directly to the blank (ManagerID) field in the records or re-writing the current records altogether?

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a work around for my problem. I had a table with one field missing so I created another table and deleted the records as I add them to the new table -

```
Private Sub CmdAppend_Click()

Dim db1 As Database
Dim rstChe As Recordset2
Dim rstCom As Recordset2
Dim qdfChe As DAO.QueryDef
Dim qdfCom As DAO.QueryDef
Dim countlbl As Integer
Dim lblstr As String
Dim stfid As String


Set db1 = CurrentDb
Set qdfChe = db1.QueryDefs("Get_TL_NTL")
qdfChe.Parameters(0) = [Forms]![TeamLeader]![ComClientNotFin]
qdfChe.Parameters(1) = [Forms]![TeamLeader]![ComDateSelect]
Set rstChe = qdfChe.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)

Set rstCom = db1.OpenRecordset("CompletedChecklistResults", dbOpenDynaset)

rstCom.MoveFirst
rstChe.MoveFirst

If rstChe.BOF Then
    MsgBox ("your form did not save please contact administrator")
    Else
    rstChe.MoveFirst
    countlbl = 0
        Do Until rstChe.EOF
        countlbl = countlbl + 1
            rstCom.AddNew
                rstCom!DateofChecklist = rstChe.Fields("DateofChecklist").Value
                lblstr = Form.Controls("SC" & countlbl).Controls(0).Caption
                stfid = Right(lblstr, 7)
                rstCom!StaffID = rstChe.Fields("StaffID")
                rstCom!ClientID = rstChe.Fields("ClientID")
                rstCom!ManagerID = stfid
                rstCom!Comments = rstChe.Fields("Comments")
                rstCom!Freq = rstChe.Fields("Freq")
                rstCom!Questions = rstChe.Fields("Questions").Value
                rstCom!DateofChecklist = rstChe.Fields("DateofChecklist")
                rstCom!DateCompleted = rstChe.Fields("DateCompleted")
                rstCom!DateMngCom = DateValue(CStr(Now()))
            rstCom.Update
            rstChe.Delete
            rstChe.MoveNext
        Loop

End If
DoCmd.Close
Set db1 = Nothing
Set rstCom = Nothing
Set rstChe = Nothing
Set qdfChe = Nothing


End Sub
```